# reversing a double array with a recursive function in c without loop in the recursive part of the code

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, double

> I've been trying to reverse a double array with a recursive function without using loops in the recursive part of the code.
>
> I've written the code for integers and it works for all cases, however, I couldn't reverse the elements of the array as doubles

Is there anyone would like to comment on this at least to give a perception?

Thanks

```
  
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>


void ArrayReverse(int  x[], int N) 
{

if (N <= 1)
{
    return;
}   
else
{
    int temp;
    int j = 0;
    temp = x[j];
    x[j] = x[N-1];
    x[N-1] = temp;
    ArrayReverse(&x[1],N-2); 
    
}
    
        
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int num_of_el;
int i;

    
printf("enter the number of elements of the array: \n");

scanf("%d", &num_of_el); 

int  arr[num_of_el]; 
int  element;
int k,l;
printf("enter the elements one by one: \n");

for(i=0;i <= num_of_el - 1; i++)
{
    
    scanf("%d", &element); 
    
    arr[i] = element;
    
}

for(l=0;l <= num_of_el - 1; l++)
{
    printf("%d", arr[l]); 
}


printf("\n"); 

ArrayReverse(arr,num_of_el); 

for(k=0;k <= num_of_el - 1; k++)
{
    printf("%d", arr[k]); 
}
    return 0;              
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @mydearflowerpot Show the code that reverses an array of doubles.

Comment: to input a value of type `double` you need `scanf("%lf", &element)` ... `printf("%f", ...);` to print (`"%lf"` also works)

Comment: Thanks for the early reply, how could I forget that. Thanks Indeed pmg

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It looks like he found somebody's code of reversing an integer array and is unable to change it to reverse an array of doubles.:)

Comment: I wrote the code by myself except the reversing part, I've just started coding lately so, anyway thanks for the help in general